# How to get size of Tree Widget from contents including subitems?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

```
max_page_name = self.ui.p_tree.sizeHintForColumn(0) + 2*self.ui.p_tree.frameWidth()
```

The above code gives the size of the Tree Widget from contents but considers only the top level items. How can I get the size considering all the items including sub-items?

Comment: Just to make sure, do you want the size of all the contents or in the end the size of the whole widget?

Comment: In the end I need to make sure the minimum size gets set to just fit the longest item(including subitems)

Answer (score 1):

Right now, I am using a work-around by doing

```
self.ui.p_tree.expandAll()
max_page_name = self.ui.p_tree.sizeHintForColumn(0) + 2*self.ui.p_tree.frameWidth()
self.ui.p_tree.collapseAll()
self.ui.p_tree.setMinimumWidth(max_page_name)
```